# How mysql is ordering textual data?

Tags: python, mysql

This is the query result from some dataset of articles ordered by article title ascending with limit 10 in MySQL. Encoding is set to utf8_unicode_ci.

```
'GTA 5' Sells $800 Million In One Day
'Infinity Blade III' hits the App Store ahead of i...
‘Have you lurked her texts?’ How the directors of ...
‘Second Moon’ by Katie Paterson now on a journey a...
"Do not track" effort in trouble as Digital Advert...
"Forbes": Bill Gates wciąż najbogatszym obywatelem...
"Here Is Something False: You Only Live Once"
“That's The Dumbest Thing I've Ever Heard Of.”
[Introduction to Special Issue] The Future Is Now
1 Great Dividend You Can Buy Right Now
```

I thought ordering works by getting the position of the character in the encoding table.
like `' is 39` and `" is 34` in unicode but apostrophe `ʼ` and double quote `“` have much higher position. From my understanding `ʼ“` shouldn't make it into the result and `"` should be at the top. I'm clearly missing something here.

My goal is to order this data by title in python to get the same results as if data was ordered in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of it is that in order to get better sort orders the Unicode Collation Algorithm is used, which would (probably) convert `“` into `"` and `‘` into `'` when sorting.

Unfortunately this is not simple to emulate in Python as the algorithm is non-trivial. You can look for a wrapper library like `PyICU` to do the hard work, although I've no guarantees they'll work.